# createReactionCollector is not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Error:

```
C:\Users\dudew\Documents\LolaV2\Commands\Moderation\rules.js:30
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
                                  ^

TypeError: message.createReactionCollector is not a function
```

Code:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageReaction } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'rules',
    description: 'Server Rules',
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    /**
     * 
     * @param {MessageReaction} message 
     */
    execute(message) {
        const rulemebed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ffc7fe')
        .setTitle('Server Rules')
        .setDescription('Please click the check mark ✅ to verfiy that you read the rules and gain access to other channels')
        .setFooter('Abusing loop holes will result in fair punishment ')
        .addFields(
            {name: '#1', value:'...',},
        );
        

        message.channel.send({ embeds: [rulemebed] }).then((sentMessage) => {
            sentMessage.react("✅");
        });
        const filter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.author.id;
        };
        
        const collector = message.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
        
        collector.on('collect', async(reaction, user) => {
            const role = await message.guild.roles.fetch("916861450281156678");
            
            message.guild.members.fetch(user.id).then(member => {
                member.roles.add(role);
                member.roles.remove("916929706182459392");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

The code works just fine until I added the reaction collector starting at line 25 The goal is to make it when someone clicks the emoji "✅" they will be givin a role. I'm using discord.js v13 and node.js v16.13.0

console.log(message):

```
type: 'APPLICATION_COMMAND',
  id: '917209298331914321',
  applicationId: '914385514910584863',
  channelId: '916857940214939659',
  guildId: '521495211474550795',
  user: User {
    id: '241673282254929920',
    bot: false,
    system: false,
    flags: UserFlags { bitfield: 128 },
    username: 'Aka Slim',
    discriminator: '4848',
    avatar: '37832e1616afa1ae62ffb489abaf819c',
    banner: undefined,
    accentColor: undefined
  },
  member: GuildMember {
    guild: Guild {
      id: '521495211474550795',
      name: 'Backdoors',
      icon: '015fe350ce1549589bc98d260da3d972',
      features: [Array],
      commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
      members: [GuildMemberManager],
      channels: [GuildChannelManager],
      bans: [GuildBanManager],
      roles: [RoleManager],
      presences: PresenceManager {},
      voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
      stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
      invites: [GuildInviteManager],
      deleted: false,
      available: true,
      shardId: 0,
      splash: null,
      banner: null,
      description: null,
      verificationLevel: 'LOW',
      vanityURLCode: null,
      nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
      discoverySplash: null,
      memberCount: 4,
      large: false,
      applicationId: null,
      afkTimeout: 300,
      afkChannelId: null,
      systemChannelId: '916857940214939660',
      premiumTier: 'NONE',
      premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
      explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
      mfaLevel: 'NONE',
      joinedTimestamp: 1638077405431,
      defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
      systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
      maximumMembers: 250000,
      maximumPresences: null,
      approximateMemberCount: null,
      approximatePresenceCount: null,
      vanityURLUses: null,
      rulesChannelId: '916857940214939659',
      publicUpdatesChannelId: '916857940214939660',
      preferredLocale: 'en-US',
      ownerId: '241673282254929920',
      emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
      stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
    },
    joinedTimestamp: 1544404547421,
    premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
    deleted: false,
    nickname: 'Slim ',
    pending: false,
    _roles: [
      '523520902286147584',
      '523520896443613185',
      '916929706182459392',
      '916861450281156678',
      '523520575419973642',
      '523520815665381386',
      '914383272505671700'
    ],
    user: User {
      id: '241673282254929920',
      bot: false,
      system: false,
      flags: [UserFlags],
      username: 'Aka Slim',
      discriminator: '4848',
      avatar: '37832e1616afa1ae62ffb489abaf819c',
      banner: undefined,
      accentColor: undefined
    },
    avatar: null
  },
  version: 1,
  memberPermissions: Permissions { bitfield: 2199023255551n },
  commandId: '916934450712051753',
  commandName: 'rules',
  deferred: false,
  replied: false,
  ephemeral: null,
  webhook: InteractionWebhook { id: '914385514910584863' },
  options: CommandInteractionOptionResolver {
    _group: null,
    _subcommand: null,
    _hoistedOptions: []
  }
}
```

Comment: If the `message` variable a [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) or a [`MessageReaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction) as described by the jsdoc?

Comment: i think it's suppose to be a Message, im basing off [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector)

Comment: Log `message` and tell us what it is

Comment: I did ```console.log(message);``` under ```const collector``` and it said the same error?

Comment: do `console.log(message)` **before** `const collector =`, if you do it after, nothing will change as the code stops working on that line.

Comment: I added the console.log message to the main post

Comment: It seems to be an interaction...

Comment: Ok so i can change the code to ```interaction.createReactionCollector```? I will also change things like execute to ```execute(interaction)```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output of the `console.log`, your `message` variable is actually a [`CommandInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction), which does not have a `createReactionCollector` method.

Taking a closer look at your code, it appears you want to listen to reactions to a new message that you sent, which contains the checkmark. Thus, your code should look like this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed, MessageReaction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "rules",
  description: "Server Rules",
  permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
  
  /**
  * 
  * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
  */
  execute(interaction) {
    const rulemebed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#ffc7fe")
      .setTitle("Server Rules")
      .setDescription("Please click the check mark ✅ to verfiy that you read the rules and gain access to other channels")
      .setFooter("Abusing loop holes will result in fair punishment")
      .addFields(
        { name: "#1", value: "..." },
      );
    
    
    interaction.channel.send({ embeds: [rulemebed] }).then((sentMessage) => {
      sentMessage.react("✅");
      
      const filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return reaction.emoji.name === "✅" && user.id === interaction.user.id;
      };
      
      const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector({ filter, time: 15000 });
      
      collector.on("collect", async (reaction, user) => {
        const role = await interaction.guild.roles.fetch("916861450281156678"),
          { member } = interaction;
          
        member.roles.add(role);
        member.roles.remove("916929706182459392");
      });
    });
  }
}
```